# IBM Worklight Studio 5.0.5 | Hang up during lanuch

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

[image]

IBM Worklight Studio 5.0.5 used to work till sometime back but somehow it isn't launching now and hangs up in between then have to close forcefully from the task manager.

After closing the Worklight, could see another screen which gives the detail about the log, I am fairly new to Worklight and used to work with ADT Eclipse and getting some kind of issues using ADT, that's why shifting towards Worklight Studio but not able to run now.

[image]

Hope to get some pointers, let me know if you need more detail around the same.

Answer (score 2):

Can you look in /.metadata/.log file and see if there is any additional helpful information?  There was a bug in the previous versions of Worklight where the commons.io bundle from Worklight would conflict with the version from ADT.

Comment: I have switched to Mac now, don't have the prev. environment with me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen many times. You will have to clean out the project meta data or create a new Workspace and import the folders again.

It is a horrible work around and incredible inefficient.

Why is this caused?

From my experience, if something happens to eclipse while you are using the workspace (say a force close or improper close) it messes up the workspace/meta data/ or something in there. There have been times where I have shut down my computer and not allowed eclipse to completely closed and it caused the same issue. After that, that specific workspace would not open at all. I would have to create a new workspace and import the projects back in.

Try creating a new workspace. (It may be the way the plugin is trying to also load the ADT or other components).

I have had the issues for both versions of Worklight (plug in and also full Studio). I hope this solves the issue so you at least know what to do. I really think it needs to be fixed though. Idan, is there any ticket on this specific crash issue?

Comment: what you are describing used to happen in the past when using the Worklight Studio plug-in you install via the Eclipse marketplace, for example. This is fixed. But as for using this specific version of Worklight Studio (with this splash screen I have never seen...), I do not know.